# Bind a control attribute to an object property in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

How do I bind the attribute of a WPF control to an object I've created in code?

For example, say I have this snippet of XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="(title name here)"/>
```

and I have this class in C#:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

and I have the object:

```
Article a = new Article();
a.Title = "Foo";
```

Basically, how do I make that TextBlock always display whatever a.Title is set to?

If it helps (perhaps there's a better way to do this), in my example, I have a window with a list of articles and an article detail section. When I select an article, I want to populate the details section .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

This assumes that the DataContext for the TextBlock element is set to an instance of your Article type.  Typically though, you should aim to use MVVM in which case your view's DataContext will be your corresponding view model, and you may in this case have a property on your view model which is of type Article.  Your binding expression would then be {Binding MyArticleProperty.Title}.

For the UI to update when this property value changes in code, you need to invalidate the binding by either using dependency properties, or implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your view model.

Comment: http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html is a nice article

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `Binding` e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleProp.Title}"/>
```

Assuming you have an `ArticleProp` Property of type `Article` on the DataContext of the XAML object.

If you want the `TextBlock` to automatically update, you'll also need to make `Article` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: What is the XAML object that you refer to?

Comment: In the XAML file where you have the TextBlock tag, you'll need the ArticleProp to be a property on the DataContext.